# How difficult for a newbie? Powershell JSON File Creation and Web Scraping

Tags: powershell

I'll try to keep this short to not waste the communities' time - But I have some keyword research to do (SEO) and have noticed that it's very repetitive. How difficult would it be to **Create a Powershell script for collecting info from Google Searches (snippets, related searches, snippets of related, related of those related, with little programming knowledge?**

I have very little knowledge in Python and found the learning experience fun, so I would like to make this myself if it would be possible to make such a thing. JSON parsing in PowerShell is a format that works well with my brain, and I don't think the Python library for web scraping (starts with a C) is needed.
The process of looking into these keywords is repetitive and long, so it's worth making this if it's something I could do as a newbie, without YouTube.

I am aware of a potential issue with Google rate-limiting me and could just make it do this very slowly. That's no issue. Apparently, doing this and importing it straight into Docs is possible - if you have experience with this, would it be something I could do while learning from scratch?

I am in dire need of some thoughts on this and have tried to do everything I can to get an answer quickly. Any input is greatly appreciated.
Thanks SO

Comment: A lot of people  really don't consider powershell to be a "programming" language, due to the nature of it's purpose. So in short, it'll be a tedious process but, can definitely be done with little "*programming*" knowledge. You just gotta do it. Powershell opens up the world of the dot net framework with it's massive libraries, so a task like the one you're looking to accomplish shouldn't be too hard. Once again, you just gotta do it(:

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - My bad, I meant to call it scripting. I've received a lot of heat in the Python discord for this before with AHK. Should know better. And yeah, looking around a bit more, it looks like this will be doable. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, powershell community is definitely the most helpful out of most communities, if not all. Powershell is very forgiving, but powerful, which will make your task easier. When you have a problem with your code, post it on here and there will be plenty that'll come to the rescue. As long as some effort is put on your end. Happy learning!

Comment: I would (also) have a look into [UiPath](https://www.uipath.com/), it is a "codeless" programming language but at the other side, it can easily invoke **.Net** methods (or PowerShell, or VBScript). Meaning it will give you an easy step towards programming technics (without investing to much in a language) where you might go in depth with .Net which is underlying and used by PowerShell too. Besids UiPath has some standard activities for web scraping.